# IBM Cloud: How to search for a specific resource (service)?

Tags: ibm-cloud, command-line-interface, cloud-foundry

I have provisioned several services in my IBM Cloud account. How can I easily find a specific resource from the command line (CLI)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`ibmcloud resource` command with the `search` option](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud/cli_resource_group.html#ibmcloud_resource_search):

This finds all Cloud Foundry resources:

```
ibmcloud resource search 'type:cf-service-instance'
```

This finds all resources where the name includes "db2":

```
ibmcloud resource search 'name: *db2*'
```

Combining the two, find Cloud Foundry services with a name that includes "db2":

```
ibmcloud resource search 'name: *db2* AND type:cf-service-instance'
```

There are many more [options](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud/cli_resource_group.html#ibmcloud_resource_search) and the search syntax is based on Lucene. Some is also explained in this [cloud solution tutorial on accessing resource usage](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/cloud-usage.html#reviewing-ibm-cloud-services-resources-and-usage).